# set root viewcontroller as the delegate for nav controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, viewwillappear

Hi I understand that the usual `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` won't get called if push/pop new view on a navigation controller.  I have implemented the `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>` protocol & required methods on my root view controller.  however, I'm having a hard time setting the root view controller as the delegate of the navigation controller.  Is there a way to do this programmatically or in storyboard?

I tried

`[self.navigationController setDelegate:self]` from the root view controller's `viewWillAppear` method but seems to have no effect.  Any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: viewWillAppear and co should be called when pushing/popping view controllers.

Comment: well, there are situations when that is not the case see here, a.o.: http://davidebenini.it/2009/01/03/viewwillappear-not-being-called-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/

Comment: That post references a situation that happens when your navigation controller is a *subview* of another view controller. Typically this would rarely happen on iPhone, because your nav controller is always the root controller.

Comment: i had the same problem when i put my views in a UIScrollingViewController and these subviews use the ScrollingViewController's navigation bar, so these situations do exist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put these in the viewDidLoad for your root view controller:

```
[self.navigationController viewWillAppear:NO];  //YES if you want to animate

[self.navigationController viewDidAppear:NO];
```